# How to add to a RavenDB List<type> in .net

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

**Update: I fixed it by copy pasting the working code into a new clean project. I have no idea why I was getting that bug, but as long as it's gone**

I'm having problems figuring exactly how to do what I want.
In this instance, what I have is a db of merchants, and I want to be able to add venues as a list to the merchant entry in the database. For some reason I cannot figure out why, I can fetch the merchant, but cannot seem to get a hold of the id of the entry that I have fetched and then update it. (I'm having some problems with updating as well, From what I've seen I need the Id of the entry I want, and then I can update with a patch... right?)

Here is my Json class:

```
 public class Merchant
  {
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
     public string name { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "venues")]
     public List<Venue> venues { get; set; }

 }

public class Venue
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tills")]
    public List<Till> tills { get; set; }
}

public class Till
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my RavenDB Handler class's functions that are relevent:

```
 public List<JObject> QueryFromDb(string query)
     {
        List<Object> objReturned;
        List<JObject> jObjects = new List<JObject>();
        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            objReturned = session
            .Advanced.RawQuery<Object>(query)
            .ToList();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < objReturned.Count; i++)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objReturned[i], Formatting.Indented);
            jObjects.Add(JObject.Parse( json.ToString()));
        }

        return jObjects;
    }


    public String GetJsonFromDB(string query)
    {
        string returnStr = "";
        List<JObject> myResponse = QueryFromDb(query);
        for (var i = 0; i < myResponse.Count; i++)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse[i], Formatting.Indented);
            returnStr += json.ToString();
        }
        return returnStr;
    }
```

And here is me trying to get ahold of the Id of the ravendb entry:

```
 public void UpdateMerchantList()
    {
        merchantGrid.Rows.Clear();
        List<JObject> myResponse = ravenDB.QueryFromDb("from Merchants");
        for (var i = 0; i < myResponse.Count; i++)
        {
           var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse[i], Formatting.Indented);
           Merchant merchant = new Merchant(json.ToString());
           if (myResponse[i].Property("Id") != null) { merchant.MyID = myResponse[i].Property("Id").ToString(); }
           merchantGrid.Rows.Add(merchant.MyID, merchant.name);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, I took this code and transplanted it into a console app, and got it to work with this code:

```
  List<JObject> result = ravenDb.QueryFromDb("from Merchants");
        for(var i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result[i].Property("Id").ToString());
        }
```

Which does give me the exact stuff I want:
"Id": "merchants/97-A"
"Id": "merchants/98-A"
"Id": "merchants/129-A"
"Id": "merchants/130-A"

But when I transplant it backinto my form and try to add this to the datagridview I cannot see it anymore.

update: have been able to add to the list into the merchant class in the console app. Here is the code.

```
 public void AddVenue(string idArg,Venue venue)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {

            var merchant = session.Load<Merchant>(idArg);
            List<Venue> venuesList = new List<Venue>();
            if (merchant.venues == null) { session.Advanced.Patch(merchant, m => m.venues, venuesList); }
            else
            {
                session.Advanced.Patch(merchant,
                x => x.venues,
                venues => venues.Add(venue));
            }
            session.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Just so people understand what I'm talking about: here is the json that outputs from the form application:
[image: No metadata, no id]

Why?

when in console with pretty much identical code (copy pasted) I get this:
[image: See how much better this looks?]

I'm getting more data from one application than the other, and I really really want the id.

I'm going to refactor the code into a wcf application I guess. Just because. Maybe I'll accidentally fix it doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can load directly the object of given class, no need to handle JSON (de)serialization yourself, unless there is a specific reason to do so.

Also, using patching is more useful when you don't want to load the document (to save bandwidth). When you already have the document loaded, you can simply change it and save the changes.

See the following code for reference:

```
public class Merchant
{
    // note added Id property
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "venues")]
    public List<Venue> venues { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tills")]
    public List<Till> tills { get; set; }
}

public class Till
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}


public void MerchantsTest()
{
    using (var store = GetDocumentStore())
    {
        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(new Merchant { Id = "merchant-1", name = "merchant1", venues = new List<Venue> { new Venue { name = "venue-1A", tills = new List<Till> { new Till { name = "till-1A-first" } } } } });
            session.Store(new Merchant { Id = "merchant-2", name = "merchant2", venues = new List<Venue> { new Venue { name = "venue-2A", tills = new List<Till> { new Till { name = "till-2A-first" } } } } });

            session.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            // you can load all merchants
            var merchants = session.Query<Merchant>(null, "Merchants").ToList();

            // or load specific merchant by ID
            var merchant2 = session.Load<Merchant>("merchant-1");

            // add a venue to a loaded merchant (not using patch but simply adding the object)
            merchant2.venues.Add(new Venue { name = "venue-2B", tills = new List<Till> { new Till { name = "till-2B-first" } } });

            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the problem, I'm not able to get the id for the entries I'm returning from ravendb in my application. I've litterally just copy pasted the entire bit from my console app (that is working), but I don't get the meta data and I don't get the id... why? I've attached a picture to the original post.

Comment: You don't have the `Id` property in your `Merchant` class, so it's not deserialized from the JSON. Note that I added the `Id` property in my code sample. In the working code, you are loading raw JSON from an index (collection index), so the `Id` is present there.

Comment: That's not it, It doesn't have it now, but I still do get the id. In fact I did try that. It added a second property... also called Id for some reason, please see code above, I've fixed it by copy pasting the code into a new project. Probably was some error I'm missing.

Comment: Could it have been caused by the capitalization mismatch `Id` vs `id`?

Comment: I don't think so, as both fields in Ravendb were named Id, not ID, id, or iD. It's possible it may have been some sort of corruption in the file?